# How can we control the sequence of function execution in Python Nose test

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

In a scenario of Nose tests in python

```
class test_class(testcase):
   def test_a(self):
      print 'test1'
   def test_b(self):
      print 'test2'
   def test_c(self):
      print 'test3'
```

when i execute the nosetest, the sequence of execution keep changing.
Could some one please advise on how to provide/define a sequence for this execution.

Thanks so much in advance..

-Revant

Comment: Is the last function supposed to be `test_c`?

Comment: thanks, updated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is by design. Nose will run the tests in random order each time and makes no guarantees of the order they will run in. You can provide a `setup` method that will run before all tests in that class, and a `teardown` method that will run after all tests in that class.

The idea is to test each thing in a system in isolation, and not have results from previous tests affect other tests. If you need the tests to be ordered, then it's a sign that you need to refactor your tests.

Comment: Thanks so much, but though done with refactoring, i can rename all 3 be removing the prefix of test_ and control them using one master function call. but the number of tests might be a hit for me though I do a execute a huge set.

Comment: setup and teardown is something which i am trying now. will keep you posted

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you should have only one [assert per test](http://www.mfranc.com/unit-testing/good-unit-test-one-assert/). Having one master function will very likely make the code much uglier and difficult to manage.

Comment: woah! thats a pretty neat documentation. Thanks for the share

Comment: thanks @saq7 It actually solved some part of the problem. Now I can definitely do a better code to combine dependent scenarios.